# Android - admob publisher id and google places api key

Tags: android, admob, google-places-api

I have following 2 doubts related to keys in admob and google places api key-

1.Can I use single admob publisher id in multiple application. Will that create any problem or I have to create separate publisher id for each app.

2.If I want to create 5 android apps using google places api do I need to create 5 google places api key or I can use single key in all app.

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.Can I use single admob publisher id in multiple application. Will that create any problem or I have to create separate publisher id for each app.

You can use the same id for each app.

> 2.If I want to create 5 android apps using google places api do I need to create 5 google places api key or I can use single key in all app.

You only need one api key.